# Python and python3 side-by-side on MacOS - Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I have both anaconda 2 and anaconda 3 installed.

I would like to call `python3` and have `python3` **from anaconda 3**, and call `python` and have `python` **from anaconda 2**.

My issue is that adding anaconda**3**'s bin path to `PATH` will also add the name `python`, so that `python` from anaconda 2 gets shadowed.
*Is it possible to have a sane environment with both languages working side-by-side?*

If I do something like:

```
export PATH="/Path/to/anaconda2:/Path/to/anaconda3:$PATH"
```

Then I get what I want, since anaconda2 will shadow anaconda3's `python`, but not `python3`.  I don't know if it has any unwanted consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to work with different Python versions at the same time is to create [conda environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html).

For Python 2:

```
conda create -n py27 Python=2.7
```

Activate with:

```
source activate py27
```

For Python 3:

```
conda create -n py35 Python=3.5
```

Activate with:

```
source activate py35
```

Deactivate with:

```
source deactivate
```

Once activated, you can install single packages or the whole Anaconda distribution:

```
conda install anaconda
```

This would allow you to create more environments say for Python 3.6 or for different combination of versions of libraries.

Add this to your `.profile`:

```
pyxx() {
exec &>/dev/null
source activate $1
exec &>/dev/tty
python ${*:2}
exec &>/dev/null
source deactivate
exec &>/dev/tty
}



py27()
{
    pyxx py27 $*
}

py35()
{
    pyxx py35 $*
}
```

Now calling:

```
py27
```

would activate the environment for Python 2.7, run Python in it and
deactivate the environment after the Python process is finished.

Same goes for:

```
py35
```

Of course you could (for while) call your environments `python2` and `python3`.

Comment: That is a good answer, but I can never have both simultaneouly available, or can I? I ask because I want to build vim from source with support for both python and python3 - which means the configuration script has to be able to find both.

Comment: You would need two terminals. One for each environment. Maybe you can talk vim into activating and deactivating the environments itself. It needs bash I think.

Comment: You should be able to provide vim with the path to your Python 3 (or 2) environment, e.g. `/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question: setting your `$PATH` to find the Python 2 version of Anaconda before the Python 3 version achieves exactly what you want and is the only way (short of symlinks and/or moving actual binaries around) you can get the results you want.

...and if anyone mentions "create an alias", just run.

Comment: I'll try this for a while and see if I come across any issues.